# Dependent variable selection for loglinear segmented regression in time-series analysis of rare events

Tags: time-series, epidemiology, monitoring

My office is going to implement a bundle of infection control measures in hospital and see if it can effectively reduce the infection rate of some pathogen. The unit of measurement will be "case per thousand patient bed days". We have chosen 4 wards for implementing the control measures for 12 months, and do the measurement monthly, but by looking at the current infection data, even thses wards are considered as having the highest count of infections, they are still considered as relatively clean, as they have several months with zero measurement in rates.
I have created a regression model showing if they managed to reduce 50% of infection, and the betas in the model (with three variables inside), are not statistically significant. My colleagues are worried that with all these hard work, giving non-significant result will be very frustrating for the front line staff.

Is there any alernative outcome measure, or even alternative statistical methods, for time series of rare events? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right to conclude that there's little hope of finding a 'statistically significant' result from 4 wards over 12 months. Of course, that doesn't mean the control measures don't work — just that your sample size is far too small (and the variability too large) to have much chance of finding evidence that it's worked. I'd guess that larger studies have been done and at least some evidence exists about what control measures work, and you should assume the same measures will work in your hospital too unless you have good reason for thinking it's different.

Within your one hospital, rather than looking a the p-value(s) as the 'bottom line' i think you'd be better looking at this as performance monitoring. I quick bit of googling found a 2004 [Report from Key Indicators Joint Working Group](http://www.his.org.uk//resource_library.cfm?cit_id=243&FAArea1=customWidgets.content_view_1&usecache=false) of the [Hospital Infection Society](http://www.his.org.uk/), which may be one place to start.